# How can i query and show all the people that i invited and the people that they invited and so on?

Tags: mysql, database

Database -> Table "Customer"

Person A -> invites Person B
Person A -> invites Person C
Person A -> invites Person D
Person C -> invites Person E
Person D -> invites Person F

Person J -> invites Person K
.
.
and so on..

how should i design the table and how should i do the query to say I want to show the transaction reports for **Person A** and all of her invites. Separate query also for **Person J** and all of his invites or for **Person C** and all of her invites.

Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Please provide the proper database table structure. While asking the question you must have to provide proper information so that you will get a quick resolution for your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a self-referencing One-To-Many (that means the Class `Person` references Many `Person`s) relationship via `person->invitees`. Then you can loop through them. Go through each person, find out their invitees. Then go through the invitees' invitees and go through them.

While you are doing so, you would need to create a list and check against it as well. So, when you add to `invitationList->add(invitee)` you also need to do `!invitationList->contains(invitee)` first, because otherwise, if person A invites person B, and Person B invites person A, you will get an infinite loop. The `if` statement would break the chain.

With a One-To-Many, a person can only be invited by one person. If both person A and person B invite person C and you want the database to reflect that, you will need a Many-to-Many with a separate table showing the connections.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Oliver.
Can you share an example of how the query should be like?
On how can i query the records/transaction of Person A and show his invites along with Person C who invited Person E in one query output.

Thanks for the tip on cross checking before adding the invited person will take note of that.

Comment: You will need a complex-ish data-query for that, I feel. As a (temporary) workaround, you might be able to loop through the person + invitees in your application. Yes, it will do a lot of queries (depending on how big this event / invitee list is), but I think it would be less error-prone and simpler to understand. I.e. in a One-To-Many you would do `find person where invitedBy is_in [person A]`, then you have an invitee list. Then do a `find person where invitedBy is_in list(invitee_list)`. It's not the most efficient perhaps, but depending on your use case would get the job done.